# MAC - Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Was trying to bundle install this morning and got this error

```sh
bundle install
```

> Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

> Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <timed out (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Here is my environment

Versions

```sh
bundle -v
# Bundler version 2.2.7

asdf current
# nodejs          14.7.0
# ruby            2.7.1
```

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dry-struct', '~> 1'

  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rubocop'
  gem 'rake', '~> 12.0'
  gem 'rake-compiler', require: false
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'rubocop-rake', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', require: false
end
```

RubyGems Status looks good

[image: RubyGems Status]

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable IP6 on my WiFi adapter

Find the name of my adapter

```sh
sudo networksetup -listallnetworkservices
# An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
# Wi-Fi
# Bluetooth PAN
# Thunderbolt Bridge
```

Turn it off

```sh
sudo networksetup -setv6off 'Wi-Fi'
```

Run Bundle

```sh
bundle install
```

Turn it back on

```sh
sudo networksetup -setv6automatic 'Wi-Fi'
```